# iTunesConnectでiOSが選択できない。

Tags: xcode

お世話になります。
マイApp ⇨ AppStore の バージョンまたはプラットフォームをクリックした時、通常はiOSとtvOSを選択する吹き出しが出てきます。
ところが、iOSがグレーになってクリックできないようになっております。
下記
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

解決するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？
因みに、画像の1.4.1はまだAppleには提出前で自分で削除しました。
ビルドしたソースはTestFlightでは使用することが出来ております。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

画像の場合『1.4.1　デベロッパーにより・・・』というのがあると、新しく追加することができません。

提出取り下げ、もしくは却下されたものは、提出画面（画像の隠れている右半分を再利用する）のバージョンの項目を書き換え、ビルドを一度削除しアップロードしたものを登録し直すことによって、再提出できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やってみます。